# How to do Data Augmentation and Cross validation at the same time

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, python, cross-validation, scikit-learn

I have read somewhere that you should **not use data augmentation on your validation set, and you should only use it on your training set**.

My problem is this:

I have a dataset with few samples.
I split them into training and test set, and did data augmentation on the training set to get more examples.
The problem comes when I use StratifiedKFold cross validation.
When I use StratifiedKFold (X_train), it gives me the train index and test index of the augmented data. I do no want my validation data (test index) to have augmented data.
Is there anyway we could do cross validation and get train index which includes augmented data and test index which consists of real world data ?

Is there any way to do data augmentation on the training set and do cross-validation ?

Comment: I don't understand your problem, can't you just first separate X_train, X_test and X_eval, and then just on X_train apply Augmentation and then StratifiedKFold ?

Comment: Yea so if i apply stratified k fold on X_train, it would return train index and test index, so I don't want test index since it contains augmented data. If you are saying to just ignore the test index , that would be a wastage of training examples.

Comment: Well you can actually train your model on augmentated data (X_train augmented, split again on your CV with both train and test augmented) and then make your final test (only on X_test) on your non-augmented data, once your model is validated and tuned on your cross validation. If your really want your test from CV not to be augmented, you can use your augmentation only in the CV loop, and then for example if you do 10-FoldCV, you do 10 times an augmentation on the current train from CV. This would take longer but that's, from what I know, the only way to deal with your issue.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have one simple question is it ok if X_train and X_val comes from augmented data and keep the X_test separate with real world data? And thanks for your solution will try that!

Comment: X_val is to tune your model, so I would keep it the same structure for X_val and X_test... But well, I'm still learning Data Science so I'm not sure at all

Comment: Thank you so much! Isn't this a common problem? I am surprised that there is no solution for this problem. Any way, thank you so much for your time.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/279175)